# INNER JOIN ON IF statement results

Tags: mysql, sql

```
table2.A = 1 for display only
table2.B = 2 for display only

SELECT * FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON 
IF(A > B) 
table2.id = table1.id -- if value of A is > B then inner join table on table2.id = table1.id
ELSE IF (A < B)
table2.id = table1.somethingElse -- if value of A is < B then inner join table on table2.id = table1.somethingElse
```

How can i translate this into actual SQL?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Also, an appropriate database tag would help.

Comment: Dont have an out put desire, was just wondering how to do this with if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a CASE expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = CASE 
    WHEN (A > B) THEN table1.id
    WHEN (A < B) THEN table1.somethingElse
END
```

Note that this query still can use an index on `table2(id)`.

It's also possible to use nested `IF()` functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON
    table2.id = IF(A > B, table1.id, IF(A < B, table1.somethingElse, NULL))
```

But that's not very readable.

Also note, that in both queries there will be no match if `A = B`. But that is what your "pseudo code" suggests.

Answer (score 3):

Use `AND`/`OR` logic in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON (t2.A > t2.B AND t1.id = t2.id) OR
       (t2.A < t2.B AND t1.somethingElse = t2.id);
```

Note that your intended logic leaves open an edge case where `A = B` exactly.  Assuming you want to include this, one way would be to change one of the inequalities to either `>=` or `<=`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what exactly do you need. But probably something like this. It's in PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON
        CASE WHEN table1.A > table2.B THEN table1.id = table2.id
        ELSE table1.id = table2.id2
        END;
```